# How to: debug an ASP.NET Web-Service when called from a win-application

Tags: winforms, web-services, debugging, asmx

I have a windows forms applications that accesses a web service.

I want to debug the web service so that when I call its methods from the win-app it should stop on the breakpoints within the methods.

Comment: And? What's your question? Did you try this? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to attach to the process on the server. Possibly remote debugging will be useful for you.

Comment: Can you be more specific, I don't know how to do it.